# why list show delete item when move to landscape to portrait?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

[image]

I make a simple application when I long press on list view it show delete option .I deleted my show .It display remaining rows but when rotate my device it show again all item in list view why ?I think it call again increase method of my activity when I rotate my device so  i write in manifest file still i getting same thing why ? why is it not getting deleted?

### Activity Code

```
public class MainApplication extends Activity {

    public ArrayList<String> arrayList=new ArrayList<String>();




    String item;
    Object mActionMode;

    private ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listview_application);
        arrayList.add("Test");
        arrayList.add("Test1");
        arrayList.add("Test2");
        ListView listView= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        arrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                item =arrayList.get(position);
                if(mActionMode!=null){
                    return  false;
                }
                mActionMode=MainApplication.this.startActionMode(mactionMode);
                return true;
            }
        });


    }
    private ActionMode.Callback mactionMode = new ActionMode.Callback() {
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            mode.setTitle(item);
            MenuInflater menuInflater =mode.getMenuInflater();
            menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu,menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem ite) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"HH",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            switch (ite.getItemId()){
                case R.id.detlte_item :
                    arrayAdapter.remove(item);
                    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    mode.finish();
                    return  true;
                default:
                    return false;

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            mActionMode=null;
        }
    };

}
```

[image]
**manifestfile.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.naveen.listviewapp" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:name=".MainApplication"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

[image]

Comment: Did you validate that your state is correct and the data that its displaying? We can't help you if we don't know what is the before and after of your datastructure.

Comment: ok ..I will give more information

Comment: you also have to remove item from your dataset which is your arraylist

Comment: @Pavan he is calling arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); when delete is hit.

Comment: please check my update ..I run my application on potrait ..I have 3 items .I deleted one item in portrait and item is removes form my list ..but when I move device it again show all item in listview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Add screensize to the Manifest also as currently your whole activity is restarting causing the list to be repopulated from scratch.

> Caution: Beginning with Android 3.2 (API level 13), the "screen size"
>   also changes when the device switches between portrait and landscape
>   orientation. Thus, **if you want to prevent runtime restarts due to
>   orientation change** when developing for API level 13 or higher (as
>   declared by the minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion attributes), you
>   **must include the "screenSize" value in addition to the "orientation"
>   value**. That is, you must decalare
>   android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize". However, if your
>   application targets API level 12 or lower, then your activity always
>   handles this configuration change itself (this configuration change
>   does not restart your activity, even when running on an Android 3.2 or
>   higher device).

```
 android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

Comment: please check my update ..I run my application on potrait ..I have 3 items .I deleted one item in portrait and item is removes form my list ..but when I move device it again show all item in listview

Comment: I did not require clarification. Please read my answer again. I don't think you understood it. It is telling you what your problem is and how to resolve it.

Comment: not the manifest file you posted. That one shows only `keyboardHidden` and `orientation`